# How can aliases of a folder be found using cmd?

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2008, alias

Is it possible to find the aliases that correspond to a certain folder (and perhaps its sub-directories, too) using Windows cmd? I've tried searching, but it gives me results related to creating aliases for commands, like in Bash. I'm connecting to Windows Server 2008 R2 from a Windows 7 client.

Comment: By alias, do you mean [hard links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) and/or [symlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)?

Comment: I'm mainly looking for symlinks, but both, if that's possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Symbolic links and directory junctions

With `dir`, you can list all symlinks and junctions in a specific folder and its subfolders.

If you pipe the result to `find`, you can filter out any links that do not interest you.

Examples:

- To find all symlinks and junctions on `C:` that point to `C:\Users`, use

  ```
    dir C:\ /al /s | find /i "[C:\Users]"
  ```
- To find all symlinks and junctions on `C:` that point to `C:\Users` or one of its subdirectories, use

  ```
    dir C:\ /al /s | find /i "[C:\Users\"
  ```

Unfortunately, this won't tell *where* the files are located. [grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) gives better results:

Examples:

```
dir C:\ /al /s | grep -Pi "Directory of|\[C:\\Users\]"
```

```
dir C:\ /al /s | grep -i "Directory of\|\[C:\\Users\\\\"
```

Note that you have to escape the brackets, double the backslashes and quadruple a trailing backslash.

#### Hard links

Because hard links are directly associated to a file by the file system, it's much easier/faster to find them.

To find all hard links to `file`, use

```
fsutil hardlink list file
```